Union/merge overlapping coplanar mesh faces
After converting a beveled curve to a mesh, I have many instances of coplanar faces that overlap each other. How can I perform the equivalent of a Union in Illustrator, simplifying the geometry so no faces overlap?



This answer works some of the time, but requires manual intervention:

Select the mesh with the overlapping coplanar faces.

Enter Edit mode (tab).

Select all vertices (a).

In the top right of the viewport, enable "Auto Merge Vertices", enable "Split Edges & Faces" in the Options dropdown, and set the Threshold to the highest value you can accept.


Nudge the selection without actually moving it (g y 0 Enter).


This will merge most of the faces...


...but in some cases it may leave either overlapping faces or (worse) holes in your surface.

Where this happens you can manually select the problematic region and use Mesh > Clean Up > Merge By Distance and play with the value until you get a good planar result:


Not a good answer, but: you can

Convert the curve to Grease Pencil
Export as SVG
Open in Adobe Illustrator
Stroke to desired width
Outline stroke to create new paths
Save as SVG
Re-import to Blender as Grease Pencil
Convert Grease Pencil to Poly Curve (Bezier curves have fill problems with certain hole configurations)
Set curve to 2D (after rotating to XY plane), and enable fill:both
Manually select inside and outside loops and press F to fix the inside/outside fills

Now you have a curve that's the same shape, without overlapping pieces, and you can convert this to a Mesh if you desire. (Or, if you're using it for a knife project as I was, you can use the curve directly.)
I won't accept this as the answer as it requires an outside tool like Adobe Illustrator.
